# Will HardiePlank withstand heat from an outdoor grill?

Tags: kitchens, outdoor

I've framed out my outdoor kitchen and plan to use brickwebb on the front. However, for the sake of cost, I'd like to use HardiePlank on the back, painted to match our pool pavilion and house.

Will the painted siding be able to withstand the heat from a drop in grill and/or [Egg](https://biggreenegg.com/egg-works/)?

[image: Partially covered patio with workbench framing]

Comment: Unfortunately, this boils down to a matter of opinion and/or decorating advice, both of which are off topic here. If you were to ask a more objective question like "is HardiPlank designed to last in an outdoor setting like this" then you will get an objective answer. (The answer is "yes", BTW, it's used for house siding.)

Comment: Really nice looking space, BTW. Well done!

Comment: I guess I should've specified; can painted Hardie withstand grill heat from a drop in and/or egg?  And thanks!!

Comment: What is "the back"? What sort of clearance from the grill? What exterior grill temperatures? What paint? There are too many unknowns here for anyone to give you a confident answer. I'd contact Hardie and discuss the situation.

Comment: Took me a while to realize that a "drop in ... egg" wasn't a broken egg, but a smoker/grill brand name. Capitalization helps with that.

Comment: Some stoves and ranges have "minimum distance to combustible materials" specifications in their instruction manuals. Maybe your grille does too? Or you can get it from the manufacturer?

Comment: Well, they will literally sell you a [wood table for your Egg](https://www.acehardware.com/departments/outdoor-living/grills-and-smokers/charcoal-grills/8797961-collection) so use paint that's rated for high temps I guess. I think Hardie Board has a 1-hour fire rating? Quite frankly, I'd be much more worried about your pergola catching fire. Check out https://decksbye3.com/deck-grill-clearance/ but more importantly, contact the manufacturer.